# get simple json object using retrofit 2

Tags: android, json, retrofit

My api prints a simple json object like this:

```
{"status":1}
```

How to say that retrofit (v2) pass it to gson and return an JSONObject contains this key-value pair in response?

I tried following:

```
Call<JSONObject> result();
```

But when prints `response.body()` in `onResponse (Response<JSONObject> response)` method, it returns `{}` which means it's empty.

Comment: Have you tried accessing  `response.raw().body()` ?

Comment: did you get the solution?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

After lots of R&D I got answer. Please find it below

Use `JsonObject` from package `com.google.gson` instead of `JSONObject` from package `org.json`

After that call `Call<JsonObject> result()` and in `onResponse (Response<JsonObject> response)` method used to call `response.body()` or `response.body().toString();` it wil print correct Json from apiwhatever you want

Comment: Awesome! God bless you.

Comment: Good stuff man. I tried this earlier today with JSONObject. Never would have noticed the difference (JsonObject). Would upvote again if I could.

Comment: I need to upvote this answer a million times! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

To get org.json.JSONArray or org.json.JSONObject just create custom ConverterFactory like here:
https://github.com/marcinOz/Retrofit2JSONConverterFactory

Comment: Slightly modified version of this worked perfectly for me, thank you!