# Rxjava2 with retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit, rx-java2

> Am newly implementing the RxJava2 with retrofit , have implemented everything and wanted to get the result as JSONObeject

```
 Map<String, String> requestBody = new HashMap<>();
        requestBody.put("username", "xyz");
        requestBody.put("password", "abc");
   Single<ResponseBody> singleResponse = myService.loginWithParam(requestBody);

        singleResponse.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribeWith(new DisposableSingleObserver<ResponseBody>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(ResponseBody response) {

                       response // this needs to be converted JsonObject 
                        loginResponse(response);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Throwable e) {
                        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                    }
                });
```

> ResponseBody response how do i convert this as Json object, could't find any link in online .

Comment: Nice..!, what the diff with RxJava2 using retrofit.can you explain me if possible.

Comment: Hope this helps you https://medium.com/3xplore/handling-api-calls-using-retrofit-2-and-rxjava-2-1871c891b6ae

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be easiest to get it as model object directly, retrofit can auto-parse the json into your model object: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31112346/1310343

Comment: Thanks @Frank, its works as model object, but is it possible to get as JSON object?

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32617770/how-to-get-response-as-string-using-retrofit-without-using-gson-or-any-other-lib