# android: How to receive response from the following json using Retrofit?

Tags: java, android, retrofit2

I have used retrofit2. but I cannot catch the response because there is always showing zero data.
How can I receive a response? I am using this code. (added debug code also for better understanding).

```
ApiClient.getApiClient().getPurchOrderEdit(map).enqueue(new Callback<Map<String, Map<String, List<Map<String, Object>>>>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Map<String, Map<String, List<Map<String, Object>>>>> call, Response<Map<String, Map<String, List<Map<String, Object>>>>> response) {
                System.out.println("test");
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Map<String, Map<String, List<Map<String, Object>>>>> call, Throwable t) {

            }
        });
```

[image]

```
{
    "TBLT_PURCHASE_ORDER_EDIT": {
        "data": [
            {
                "column_id": "17705",
                "po_id": "15872311254332020-04-18 23:32:05",
                "db_id": "62",
                "dbhouse_name": "Coca Cola DB House",
                "depot_id": "3",
                "dpo_name": "Tongi Depot",
                "dist_emp_id": "140",
                "first_name": "Coca cola DB",
                "order_date": "2020-04-18",
                "total_order": "1056",
                "total_quantity": "24"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you asking how to parse this json?

Comment: this aswer will help you to pasrse json directly into class objects with retrofit https://stackoverflow.com/a/31112346/5701085

Answer (score 0):

Make your `API` call to return `ApiResult`

Your `ApiResult` class:

```
public class ApiResult {

    private String status;
    private JsonElement result;

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public JsonElement getResult() {
        return result;
    }

    public void setResult(JsonElement result) {
        this.result = result;
    }

}
```

Use this code inside of Api  `onResponse` and replace `YourDataObject` with your data class :

```
 Type typeToken = new TypeToken<List<YourDataObject>>() {
                            }.getType();

 List<YourDataObject> list = new ArrayList<>();

list = new Gson().fromJson(response.body().getResult().getAsJsonObject()
                                                .getAsJsonArray("data"), typeToken);
```

Comment: Cannot resolve method 'getGson' and Cannot resolve method 'getResult()' @Krishna_Sony

Comment: ```getGson()``` remove and use ```Gson.fromJson(response.body().getResult().getAsJsonObject()
                                                .getAsJsonArray("data"), typeToken);```

Comment: did you use ApiResult as the return type of your  ```getPurchOrderEdit(map)```

Comment: Replace result with ```TBLT_PURCHASE_ORDER_EDIT``` and remove status field from ApiResult